# how can i get in openldap dn:dc=,dc=,dc=

Tags: openldap

This is my first experience with openldap.

server Ubuntu 14.04

when i run `hostname -f`

i get `name.org.test.`

When i give the next command

```
ldapsearch -x -LLL -H ldap:/// -b dc=name,dc=org,dc=test dn.
```

I get 
No such object (32)
Matched DN: dc=org,dc=test.

How can i get:
`dn:cn=name,cn=org,cn=test`

So when i create a ou people i get:
`ou=people,dc=name,dc=org,dc=test`

grts

Comment: allready find out how to fix with reconfigure slapd.

But the question stay's what's the difference that it's works with reconfigure and not standard?

Comment: Unanswerable. What was the initial configuration, and what did you change it to?